# Roof Flashing inside corner

Tags: roof, flashing

I'm building a structure and putting a roof on it.  The roof is single slope 3x12 pitch.  Basically it's rectangle platform except where in the middle of the lower edge the roof extends 2 more feet so I have two inside corners.  The drip edge flashing goes under the felt paper and the side flashing goes over the felt paper but how to I flash these inside corners?

Comment: A drawing would be really helpful....

Comment: You could Google “GAF roofing shingles installation”. Or look on YouTube for videos for your particular situation. Each roofing manufacturer has specific requirements for nailing, underlayment, flashing, etc.   I’d go to your particular brand of roofing and follow their requirements.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more information before we could help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.